# How in JS to execute inside a batch loop only on first iteration one function

Tags: javascript

On the following snippet inside the `forEach` loop, I'm executing a function called
`saveCandidatesData({ screeningNumbers, pruneScreeningNumbers: prune })`

The function generally is about saving some data in batches not to overload the request.

My issue is that the function `saveCandidatesData` need to be executed for every batch but the part called `pruneScreeningNumbers` needs to be executed only on the first batch iteration.

For example

If you have 3 batches then request `saveCandidatesData` should be executed 3 times.

1. screeningNumbers - data for batch 1 + pruneScreeningNumbers
2. screeningNumbers - data for batch 2 (no prune)
3. screeningNumbers - data for batch 3 (no prune)

I don't know how to implement this in the following code

```
const screeningNumbersCalculations = async (data, batches) => {
  console.log('batches: ', batches);
  const results = {};
  const mappedDateId = dateIdMap(data);

  batches.map(b => {
    b.forEach(t => {
      const matchingStatusesTime = Object.values(mappedDateId).filter(s => {
        return new Date(s.statusFrom) < endOfDay(t) && (s.statusTo === null || new Date(t) <= new Date(s.statusTo));
      });

      matchingStatusesTime.forEach(ms => {
        const label = assignLabel(ms.statusType, ms.eligible);
        const key = `${t}${ms.studyId}${ms.siteId}${label}`;
        if (!results[key]) {
          results[key] = {
            days: [t],
            studyId: ms.studyId,
            siteId: ms.siteId,
            screeningStage: 'SELF_ASSESSMENT',
            label,
            total: 0,
          };
        }
        results[key].total += 1;
      });
      const screeningNumbers = Object.values(results);

      const cnt = saveCandidatesData({ screeningNumbers, pruneScreeningNumbers: prune });

      log.info('Replay screening numbers completed in %d', cnt);
    });
    return Promise.resolve();
  });
};
```

Right now the `prune` is executed every time and I need to change that to be only on the first batch iteration.

I have no clue how to fix that

This is a working snippet of a simplified version of the above snippet but without the function at the moment. However, you can have an idea on how it works

```js
const mockData = [{
    id: "C10-TBX4",
    studyId: "TBX4",
    siteId: "USA-1",
    statusType: "INCOMPLETE",
    statusFrom: "2020-12-05T01:00:00.000Z",
    statusTo: "2020-12-05T02:00:00.000Z"
  },
  {
    id: "C10-TBX4",
    studyId: "TBX4",
    siteId: "USA-1",
    statusType: "DROPOUT_PRESCREENER",
    eligible: true,
    statusFrom: "2020-12-05T02:00:00.000Z",
    statusTo: "2020-12-05T03:00:00.000Z"
  },
  {
    id: "C10-TBX4",
    studyId: "TBX4",
    siteId: "USA-1",
    statusType: "INCOMPLETE",
    statusFrom: "2020-12-05T03:00:00.000Z",
    statusTo: null
  }
];

function endOfDay(time) {
  const date = new Date(time);
  date.setUTCHours(23, 59, 59, 999);
  return date;
}

const assignLabel = (statusType, eligible) => {
  if (statusType === "INCOMPLETE") return "pending";
  if (statusType === "REJECTED_PRESCREENER") return "ineligible";
  if (statusType === "DROPOUT_PRESCREENER" && eligible) return "eligible";
  if (statusType === "DROPOUT_PRESCREENER" && !eligible) return "abandoned";
  return "completed";
};

// This dates are generated from a fuction bases on which dates range we need
// In this cas is just one day
const batches = ["2020-12-05T00:00:00.000Z"];

const screeningNumbersCalculations = () => {
  const results = {}; // Dont use array since you are using it as dictionary Object.
  // Putting latest records at end so we can confidently overwrite with records of same day in next step
  mockData.sort((a, b) => endOfDay(a).getTime() - endOfDay(b).getTime());
  const dateidMap = mockData.reduce((accum, item) => {
    accum[`${endOfDay(item).getTime()}.${item.id}`] = item;
    return accum;
  }, {});
  console.log(dateidMap)
  batches.forEach((t) => {
    // or filter matching times first and generate dateidMap later.
    const matchingStatusesTime = Object.values(dateidMap).filter((s) => {
      return (
        new Date(s.statusFrom) < endOfDay(t) &&
        (s.statusTo === null || new Date(t) <= new Date(s.statusTo))
      );
    });

    matchingStatusesTime.forEach((ms) => {
      const key = `${t}${ms.studyId}${ms.siteId}${assignLabel(
        ms.statusType,
        ms.eligible
      )}`;
      if (!results[key]) {
        results[key] = {
          days: [t],
          studyId: ms.studyId,
          siteId: ms.siteId,
          screeningStage: "SELF_ASSESSMENT",
          label: assignLabel(ms.statusType, ms.eligible),
          total: 0
        };
      }
      results[key].total++;
    });
  });
  return Object.values(results);
};
const screeningNumbers = screeningNumbersCalculations();

console.log(JSON.stringify(screeningNumbers, null, 2));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`map()` receives the array index as the 2nd argument. So you can test if this is `0` to tell if you're in the first batch.

Also, you should use `forEach()` rather than `map()` if you don't need the array of the results of each call that `map()` creates.

You need to move the code that calls `saveCandidatesData` to the outer loop. And you should initialize `results = {}` at the beginning of this loop so you don't combine each batch with the previous batches.

```js
const screeningNumbersCalculations = async(data, batches) => {
  console.log('batches: ', batches);
  const mappedDateId = dateIdMap(data);

  batches.forEach((b, batch_index) => {
    const results = {};

    b.forEach(t => {
      const matchingStatusesTime = Object.values(mappedDateId).filter(s => {
        return new Date(s.statusFrom) < endOfDay(t) && (s.statusTo === null || new Date(t) <= new Date(s.statusTo));
      });

      matchingStatusesTime.forEach(ms => {
        const label = assignLabel(ms.statusType, ms.eligible);
        const key = `${t}${ms.studyId}${ms.siteId}${label}`;
        if (!results[key]) {
          results[key] = {
            days: [t],
            studyId: ms.studyId,
            siteId: ms.siteId,
            screeningStage: 'SELF_ASSESSMENT',
            label,
            total: 0,
          };
        }
        results[key].total += 1;
      });
    });
    const screeningNumbers = Object.values(results);

    const options = {
      screeningNumbers
    };
    if (batch_index == 0) {
      options.pruneScreeningNumbers = prune;
    }
    const cnt = saveCandidatesData(options);

    log.info('Replay screening numbers completed in %d', cnt);
    return Promise.resolve();
  });
};
```

Comment: Unfortunately didn't solve my issue the prune is still executed many times instead of one

Comment: It's executed for every value in the first batch.

Comment: The prune has to be executed one per batch as my example

I can have 3 batches with values  and I have prune only with the first batch not for every value in the batch.

So 3 batches

1st batch -->  screening numbers + prune
1sd batch --> screening numbers no prune
etc...

Can you help with that?

Comment: But you're calling `saveCandidatesData()` in the inner loop, so it's called for each `t`.

Comment: I've added code to also check the index in the `b.forEach` loop. So it will only add `prune` in the first item of the first batch.

Comment: How can it be executed only once for each batch? The value of `screeningNumbers` is different for each `t`.

Comment: I don't know, I have that as a requirement. Not sure how to achieve that

Comment: Yes now seems to work correctly but the prune data length is 0 so need to debug what wrong then